# MySQL connection fails from spring boot but successful from command line

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot project with MySQL. The connection to MySQL DB fails from Eclipse with error as:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
 (using password: YES)
 2022-07-17 10:50:56.508  INFO 3756 --- [  restartedMain]
 com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
 2022-07-17 10:50:57.708 ERROR 3756 --- [  restartedMain]
 com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception
 during pool initialization.
 
 java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
(using password: YES)     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828)
~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448)
~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241)
~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]     at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]     at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364)
~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476)
~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561)
~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]  at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]     at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]     at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494)
~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
~[spring-orm-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]   at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]    at com.shg.SelfHelpGroupApplication.main(SelfHelpGroupApplication.java:10)
~[classes/:na]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
Method) ~[na:na]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
~[na:na]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
~[na:na]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na] at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
 ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
```

The connection parameters I'm using are:

```
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shg
> spring.datasource.username=root spring.datasource.password=root
> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
> spring.jpa.show-sql=true server.port=8091
```

However the connection with same user and password combination works from command line.

```
> C:\Users>mysql -u root -p 
   Enter password: **** 
   Welcome to the MySQL
> monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g. Your MySQL connection id is 8
> Server version: 8.0.29 MySQL Community Server - GPL
> 
> Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
> 
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
> affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.
> 
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input
> statement.
> 
> mysql>
```

I tried multiple things, but nothing is working. Any help will be much appriciated.!

Comment: What is the error stack like?

Comment: I updated the complete stack trace above.

Comment: This like might be helpful for formatting the question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL command line uses a different connection by default when you specify localhost compared to JDBC. It uses a unix socket file. I believe you can use a socket file in JDBC with something like this.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shg?localSocket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

You can also set the mysql client to use tcp (to get the same error as JDBC) instead of using a socket file with something like this to match the behavior of the JDBC connection.

```
mysql -u root --protocol=tcp -p
```